# How do I write a script that alerts a input value given by a visitor?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in javascript. I need to code a basic script that alerts the input value given by visitor.

Here is my code:

```js
function alertFunction() {
  var x.value = document.getElementById("student-name");
  alert(x.value);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="name">Student Name: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="student-name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="alertFunction()" value="Enter" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There is something wrong. Please write me the correct one. Thanks much. Have a great day.

Comment: If you look in the console, you can see that `var x.value` is producing a syntax error at the `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do X.value = dom element. Do this instead

```
function alertFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("student-name").value;
  alert(x);
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="name">Student Name: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="student-name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="alertFunction()" value="Enter" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `value` property to get value of the element.

```
function alertFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("student-name").value;
   alert(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Simple you can declare your button as below in td

```
<td><button onclick="alertFunction()">Enter</button></td>
```

And in Function use the below code to get the value

```
var x = document.getElementById("student-name").value;
```